# Function that should upload and deploy web-app doesn't work correctly

Tags: python, wildfly, web-deployment

I was given the task (re)deploy web-application on AS wildfly through http rest appi.
Function works, but there is problem.
So function:

```
def upload_and_deploy(server, app):
    try:
        pass
        files = {'file': open(distr_path + '/app-01.001.02-028.war', 'rb')}
        response = requests.post('http://' + server + ':9990/management/add-content', files=files, auth=HTTPDigestAuth('login', 'password')).text
        response_converted_to_json = json.loads(response)
        bytes_value_from_response = response_converted_to_json["result"]["BYTES_VALUE"]
        json_start = '{"content":[{"hash": {"BYTES_VALUE" : "'
        json_end = '"}}], "address": [{"deployment":"'+ app + '"}], "operation":"add", "enabled":"true"}'
        full_json_for_deploy_request = json_start+bytes_value_from_response+json_end
        print '>>>>>>', full_json_for_deploy_request
        response = requests.post('http://' + server + ':9990/management', auth=HTTPDigestAuth('login', 'password'), data= (full_json_for_deploy_request), headers=headers)
        print "Start", app, "code -", response.status_code

    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        print 'Server - %s not run' % server
```

Result looks good:

```
>>>>>> {"content":[{"hash": {"BYTES_VALUE" : "t3W62oVUihsqyINy9rRG/T3DuI4="}}], "address": [{"deployment":"app-name"}], "operation":"add", "enabled":"true"}
Start app-name code - 200
```

AS logs looks not typical, but without errors:

```
2017-10-09 10:07:07,688 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (XNIO-1 task-9) WFLYDR0001: Content added at location /opt/platform/wildfly-9.0.2.Final/standalone/data/content/b7/75bada85548a1b2ac88372f6b446fd3dc3b88e/content
2017-10-09 10:07:07,704 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "app-name" (runtime-name: "app-name")
2017-10-09 10:07:07,983 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (XNIO-1 task-2) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "app-name" (runtime-name : "app-name")
```

So application is running, but not working.
Can somebody give me a cue, what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deployment name needs to end in a valid archive extension so the appropriate processing happens. In your case it should end in `.war`.

The `json_end` should look something like the following.

```
json_end = '"}}], "address": [{"deployment":"'+ app + '.war"}],"operation":"add", "enabled":"true"}'
```